# Very basic ios help needed

Tags: ios

I m very very new to this place and want to know how to implement this:

[Make UINavigationBar transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315862/iphone-sdk-make-uinavigationbar-transparent)

Where do i write all these codes or just give me a way and i'll follow. Will be very thankful to every helpful answer.

Answer (score 2):

You would place the code you are referencing in the following location:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    ...
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    ...
}
```

Good Luck.