# Transparent Top Bar ios7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

Is there a way to make Top Bar background absolutely transparent? I'd like the page title to be visible along with buttons but make the rest completely invisible? Anything I can do with the appearance API?

Comment: Can you put some example ? What code have you tried ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone SDK - make UINavigationBar transparent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315862/iphone-sdk-make-uinavigationbar-transparent). Specifically check my answer about iOS 7: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315862/iphone-sdk-make-uinavigationbar-transparent/18969823#18969823

Answer (score 1):

that's something that i was looking into and it seems like it has to do with the meta tag in the beginning of the page

i found out that if your using

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />
```

then you have a transparent background, only with white text and icons, there's no way to change it into black/dark text to fit into anyones CSS.

also you have an issue where the top of the page is right at the pixel line of the iOS 7 device.

which is retarded

i've been doing tests on [here](http://mylesbigdealbrown.com/test)