# Changing the colour of Custom Navigation Controller Bar Buttons

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

I'm currently using iOS7, and I'm trying to set the Navigation Bar to translucent, with a clear colour background, because I have a background that I want to show through the navigation bar. However, it is proving much more difficult than anticipated, as I can't change the alpha without changing the overall colour of the bar itself. Here is where the bulk of the code affecting this is.

```
self.deckDropDown.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.deckDropDown.layer setBorderWidth:1];
[self.deckDropDown.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.90 alpha:1.0].CGColor];
self.deckDropDown.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tableView.backgroundView = tempImageView;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

If anyone could help me out with this rather frustrating problem, it'll be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: This works for me in iOS7:

`[navigation.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`
`navigation.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];`
`navigation.navigationBar.translucent = YES;`

via the excellent [Gabriele Petronella](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315862/make-uinavigationbar-transparent)

Comment: I've tried using that, I didn't include that aspect in the original question, apologies. I need a translucent bar with an almost clear, semi-transparent white sheen over it. I'm not quite sure how to do word it much myself!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes, very helpful, I had noticed that before I asked the above question.