# UINavigationBar needs to be transparent

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I have got UINavigationBar styling set in AppDelegate but it doesn't seem to be taking effect on my app. I am using XCode 5 and my code is as follows:

```
- (void) customizeApp

{
    UIImage* menuBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu-bar.png"];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:menuBackground forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    // Customize the title text for *all* UINavigationBars
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
      UITextAttributeTextColor,
      [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8],
      UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
      [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, -1)],
      UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
      [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:0.0],
      UITextAttributeFont,
      nil]];
}
```

Im not sure what Im doing wrong and why its not working. This was working in XCode 4/iOS6

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:menuBackground forBarMetrics:
     UIBarMetricsDefault];

Comment: The bettat way is add this method where you create UINavigationController, Or add it in AppDelegate.m file under  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions method.

Comment: Also you can refer this link : [Make UINavigationBar transparent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315862/make-uinavigationbar-transparent)