# Blur UINavigationBar like the photo app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

How can I achieve a blur on a `UINavigationBar` similar to the one found in the Apple photos app?

When I use this code I cannot even see my bar:

```
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                                              forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

And in AppDelegate.m

`[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];`

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you are looking for is called `translucency`, and is the default behaviour of a`UINavigationBar`. Is this behaviour not occuring by default in your application? What have you tried so far? Some more information could help.

[Here's a link to the documentation for this property specifically.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uinavigationbar_class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/translucent)

**EDIT:** I've found a similar question on SO with an answer that may help you if you're using a custom background image for the bar. [Find it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18969823/3613537)

Comment: Code added to my post.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you can't see the navigation bar? What do you see instead? Could you take some photos or show some extended code?

Comment: When I call the `setTranslucent:YES` is what makes the bar disappear. When set to `NO` I can see the bar.

Comment: Hm. Why are you setting .backgroundColor  to white? It should be white by default, and you'd probably want to change the tint instead. Beyond that I'm not sure why you aren't getting this behaviour for free.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make a translucent navigation bar is to do nothing, since that is the default.

You are basically *preventing* that from happening. Let's look at your code:

A bar's tint color is not its color. It is the color of its buttons and images. If you make the tint color white and background color white, you are creating white buttons on a white background. That is going to be hard to see!

The color of the bar, on the other hand, is the `barTintColor`. Set that, and set the `translucent` to YES. Experiment with various `barTintColor` values and see what happens.

Do *not* set the background color, as this complicates things.

And above all do *NOT* set the background image, especially not to an empty image, since this overrides everything else and punches a hole in the navigation bar, making it completely transparent.