# UINavigationBar without backgroundColor

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I would like to create a `UINavigationBar` that doesn't has colored background.

I tried

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

and

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = nil;
```

but couldn't solve the problem. I also tried to set the same color for the nav bar that I use for the `self.view.backgroundColor`, but I couldn't override the original one. (I'm using Storyboard maybe that causes the problem, but not sure, because I can manipulate the `tintColor` with code.)

Comment: Dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315862/make-uinavigationbar-transparent

Comment: You can't set navigationBar to clear with navigationItem. You can do this by setting navigationBar hidden, and add a custom button on top-left or top-right as your navigationItem.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                             forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;

UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
//[backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"you_back_image"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; this is the image you would use as a back image
[backButton setTitle:@"back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton sizeToFit];
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem* backBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarButton;
```

and then write the method `goBack` which depends on the fact if you presented or pushed the current ViewController.

```
- (void)goBack {
//[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES] 
//[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it hides my back button, I got the same result with  `[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];`

Comment: I would suggest to create a custom backButton, I'll post the code the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

try this one in appDelegates didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method it clears navigation bar's background color

[[UINavigationBar appearance]setBarTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];