# Swift 1.2 - background image of a Table View added with a Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I need to set an image as background for a TableView  I got by adding a navigation controller to my scene. I tried using a `UIImage` but can't find where to put it in the hierarchy

since **on StackOverflow you told that using a `UIImage` is wrong.** I tried:

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "back.image_")!)
```

but I have 3 problems

- I want the background to be fixed, no scrolling.
- the background is not a fixed image, I mean, image is not related to screen size
- navigation bar hides the upper section of the image (that's why I wanted to use UIImage) is there a way to transform navigation bar clear but keep buttons visible?

So, **I come back trying to use UIImageView**. This is one of my `tableView` on Document Outline:

[image]

**If I drag a `UIImage` this is the only place where i can put it:**

[image]

With this weird result:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1 & 2 - create an image behind the table and make the table background transparent. Transparent table and cells are a bit tricky but possible. 3. make navigation bar translucent.

Comment: I made clear cell's UI elements in the Utilities, my concern are on the background. in the utilities I set Translucent on the navigation bar, but I'd like it to be transparent

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the effect you want, I would create a `UIImageView` behind the table and make the table's background color `UIColor.clearColor()`. Or you can add it to the table's view hierarchy behind the cells and use auto-layout constraints to keep its position fixed.

There are lots of existing questions on Stack Overflow about transparent navigation bars. Perhaps start with [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18969823/1445366).

Comment: Problem is, I don't know how to add the `UIImageView`, I added images in order to explain it better. Where should I put the `UIImage` in the hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed image that doesn't scroll with the table, you have to use the superview's view. This code should work:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let sasha = UIImage(named: "sasha")!

    let sashaView = UIImageView(image: sasha)

    self.view.superview!.insertSubview(sashaView, belowSubview:self.view)
}
```

Put this in the `UITableViewController`. Fixed image when scrolling.