# Make ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController NavigationBar transparent

Tags: swift, xlpagertabstrip

I am using the XLPagerStrip pod in my current app and I would like to extend the tableviewcontroller inside my ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController under the nav bar and have users able to see it through the text that is on button bar navigation bar.  To do this usually I would make my navigation by transparent like from the examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315862/make-uinavigationbar-transparent), however it doesn't seem to work with the ButtonBar.  I am wondering if there was an easy way to do this or if this is unsupported by the library currently? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the link I posted above and on creation of the bar controller setting its navigation bar.  This made it transparent.