# How to pin a UIView underneath the iOS 11 NavigationBar's changing height frame?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios11, mobile-development

I have a navigation bar and a collection view programmatically added to my app and I am trying to add in a custom view as well. I have gotten the view to sit above the collection view and beneath the navigation bar, which is what I want, however, on iOS 11, the navigation bar has a changing height depending on if you stretch the collection view down. I would like to make the view move downwards as well so that there is not a gaping white space between the collection view and the navigation bar, as my custom view does not move downwards further since the view's safeInsets do not change. It will move upwards towards the collapsing title and that is not an issue.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.title = "Home"

    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    collectionView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    //collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 50, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    //collectionView?.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 50, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

    collectionView?.register(StockCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellid")

    setupMenuBar()
}

let menuBar: MenuBar = {
    let mb = MenuBar()
    mb.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    mb.backgroundColor = .black
    return mb
}()

private func setupMenuBar() {
    view.addSubview(menuBar)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        (collectionView?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: menuBar.bottomAnchor))!,
        (collectionView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor))!,
        (collectionView?.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor))!,
        menuBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
        menuBar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1),
        menuBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor)
    ])

}
```

[This is the starting screen, showing the view in its resting position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAF8B.png)

[This is the navigation bar overlapping the view, which is what I want to fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eqt9O.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way around it without using constraints between the navigation bar and the menubar since they aren't in the same view hierarchy.

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < -50) {
        let val = (-50 - scrollView.contentOffset.y)
        menuBar.frame.origin.y = val - 0.5
    }
}
```

By overriding this function, the menubar will move its y-offset down and it retains the pinning function to the top when scrolling down the collection view.

Answer (score 1):

You can constraint the custom menu view's bottom anchor to the navbar's bottom anchor; this way the menu view will always stick to the same vertical offset (you might have to adept some of your other constraints though):

```
navigationController!.navigationBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: menuBar.bottomAnchor)
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48691715/5471218) for an extended example.